# EPS figures created with MATLAB, edited with Illustrator, Different Colors in after dvipdf prepared PDF

Tags: matlab, latex, adobe-illustrator, eps

I create figures in MATLAB, and export to EPS using the normal File->Save As dialog box. I added some additions to the EPS file using Adobe Illustrator CS6, and then saved the EPS again. Viewing the EPS file with Evince, everything looks normal.
But when adding these figures to a LaTEX file, compiling as normal, then converting the .dvi to a PDF using dvipdf, the colors of the Illustrator modified EPS come out different. Any ideas what can be done to fix them?

Comment: Have you tried using pdflatex to compile your document instead? This will create a PDF directly, without the intermediate DVI step.

Comment: I haven't, because the paper is for a journal that only takes EPS figures, and as I understand it pdflatex requires you to convert EPS figures to PDF first.

Comment: Check the colorspace.  I'm not sure, but I think that dvi2pdf converts to rgb, so if your figure is cmyk, the colors will come out a little different.  The place to search for an answer to this question is actually [TeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).  I can guarantee it's already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by the following procedure. When you save the EPS file in illustrator, DO NOT check the "Include CMPK PostScript in RGB Files". Then the colors in the compiled LaTeX file won't be in dull color.